# How to Print SPList in reverse from code behind C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, development, caml-query, calendar

I'm trying to bind the last items of my list this is my code

```
          SPList myList = myWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Calendar List");

          SPListItemCollection items = myList.Items;

          EventCal.DataSource = items;
          EventCal.DataBind();
```

I tried this but it said that I'm missing a directive.

```
           EventCal.DataSource = items.Reverse();
```

this is my condition..

```
       protected void EventCal_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {



         if (e.Item.ItemIndex >= 3)
         {
             System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = e.Item.FindControl("listItem") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;
            div.Visible = false;


         }



    }
```

and thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CAML Query to fetch data in descending order of creation. And to achieve this you can sort ID column in descending order.

```
SPList myList = myWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Calendar List");
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>";
SPListItemCollection items = myList.GetItems(spQuery);
```

Once you achieve items in descending order you can go ahead and achieve what you need.